# Limpiar o redireccionar después de enviar datos en php o javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hola necesito limpiar o redireccionar mi formulario esta echo con php, a parte de redireccionar con header quiero hacerlo de otra manera e intentado meter js pero no se como incorporarlo dentro de php

```js
case "Borrar":

                $sentenciaSQL= $conexion->prepare("SELECT imagen FROM proyectos WHERE id_proyectos=:id_proyectos");
                $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(':id_proyectos',$txtID_Proyects);
                $sentenciaSQL->execute();
                $libro=$sentenciaSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);

                if(isset($libro["imagen"])&&($libro["imagen"]!="imagen.jgp")){

                    if(file_exists("imagenes/".$libro["imagen"])){

                        unlink("imagenes/".$libro["imagen"]);
                    }


                }

                    $sentenciaSQL= $conexion->prepare("DELETE  FROM proyectos WHERE id_proyectos=:id_proyectos");
                     $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(':id_proyectos',$txtID_Proyects);
                     $sentenciaSQL->execute();
                    
                    //  header("Location:portafolio.php");
                   
                //echo "Presionado el boton Borrar";
                break;
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes utilizar el evento `onClick` de javascript, que reconoce el clickeo de botones, enlaces, etc, y con ello poder limpiar el formulario, aqui hay informacion -> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Answer (score 0):

Al botón le puede agregar la función cuando le des clic.

```
<button onclick='limpiar()'>borrar</button>
```

JS

```
<script>
  function limpiar() {
    var imagen = document.getElementById('imagen');
    imagen.innerHTML = '';
  } 
</script>
```